# useHttpOnly="true" is not useful when I configed in my tomcat6.0.35

Tags: java, tomcat6

As I have said in the title,when I have set useHttpOnly="true" in the context.xml

but I still can get the jessionid in my javascript.Is there something I have forgotten to config?

Comment: Did you verify that the value has been set correctly in the cookie?

Comment: I have verify that the value hasn't been set in the cookie.But I have set in the tomcat's context.xml.While use 
String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly");It is useful.